# echo -n is not working in zsh

Tags: echo, zsh, prezto

I am trying to truncate a file in Red Hat 4.8.5-11. I have zsh+prezto installed on my system. I am getting error:
"zsh: file exists: {file_name}"

I am running following command:

```
echo -n > {file_name}
```

Same command is running just fine in bash. What could possibly be wrong?

Comment: Have you tried running the same command using `sudo` i.e `sudo echo -n > <filename>`

Comment: I did. Infact, I am working as a root user -I know thats a bad habit. But it is my local system I can afford the luxury of deleting something accidentally :)

Comment: Can you edit your question and show the exact command you're running and the output from the same?

Comment: Edited the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by the no-clobbering setting which protects you from accidently overwriting a file: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-file-clobbering_002c-allowing

You can either force it using the pipe character:

```
echo -n >| {file_name}
```

Or you can disable this behaviour by enabling clobbering:

```
setopt clobber
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Works like a charm.